# i have an error concerning a file name "flutter_01.log" after typing flutter doctor, can you help me?

Tags: flutter

hello I installed flutter and android studio, but I encounter this problem when I type flutter doctor. the path I put for android studio is correct. help me!

i tried to run the command "flutter doctor" , and i have this error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZQZq.png)